# Show data in the Curve

Tags: python

I am a event problem on the pyqt4
How should I debug the code? I found our some issuse. check the line 5

```
import sys
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
from PyQt4 import QtCore

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import Navigation as NavigationToolbar    
       FigureCanvas(self,QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding                               

class MatplotlibWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUi()
    def initUi(self):
        self.layout = QVBox(self)
        self.mpl = plut(self, width=100, height=20, dpi=100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the following errors

- A canvas is being created inside the canvas unnecessarily.
- You should not use pyplot if you use the canvas but the AxesSubplot

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=10, height=4, dpi=100):
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi))
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.on_move)
        self.po_annotation = []

    def start_static_plot(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            x = i
            y = x ** 2
            (point,) = self.axes.plot(x, y, "-o")
            annotation = self.axes.annotate(
                ("x=" + str(x), "y=" + str(y)),
                xy=(x + 0.7, y + 0.7),
                xycoords="data",
                xytext=(x + 0.1, y + 0.1),
                textcoords="data",
                horizontalalignment="left",
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=+0.2"),
                bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", facecolor="w", edgecolor="0.1", alpha=0.9),
            )
            annotation.set_visible(False)
            self.po_annotation.append([point, annotation])
        self.axes.set_xlim(-0.5, 10)
        self.axes.set_ylim(-5, 9.5 ** 2)

    def on_move(self, event):
        visibility_changed = False
        for point, annotation in self.po_annotation:
            should_be_visible = point.contains(event)[0]
            if should_be_visible != annotation.get_visible():
                visibility_changed = True
                annotation.set_visible(should_be_visible)
        if visibility_changed:
            self.draw()
```